# How can I capture a subtype within a generic type in a class definition?

Tags: java, generics, types, java-8, type-inference

I can't believe I cannot capture P without typing the class to a redundant 2-type class:

```
public class MyClass<T extends List<P>> {

   T getList(/**/){}
   P getRandomElement(){ /**/ }
}
```

Do I need, really, to define and instantiate MyClass as `MyClass<String,ArrayList<String>>`, couldn't it be inferred someway?

EDIT: What I mean is I see redundant having to define `MyClass<P,T extends List<P>>` because then I need to instantiate it always as `MyClass<String,ArrayList<String>>`, and carry String everywhere. It would be nice if the language allowed something like

`MyClass<L extends List<P>>` or similar. That way, `MyClass<ArrayList<String>>` would return an `ArrayList<String>` when executing `getList()` and an `String` when executing `getRandomElement()`, nicely.

Comment: Inferred when? What error do you get for what code? Obviously you have to specify T, P and the subclass of List _somewhere_

Comment: I get an error because I need to define P as a second class type, and I cannot do same as in generic methods `<P,T extends List<P>> class MyClass<T> {}`

Comment: How is `getList` supposed to return a `T`?

Comment: @Holger T could be passed in the constructor, for instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really must have the exact type of `List` returned from `getList`, then you need the type parameter `T` as well as `P`.

```
public class MyClass<P, T extends List<P>> {
```

This way you can have a `MyClass<String, ArrayList<String>>` whose `getList` method returns an `ArrayList<String>` and a `getRandomElement` method that returns a `String`.

However, it is usually unnecessary to know the exact type of `List`.  Usually, if you have a `List`, then it doesn't matter to the user of this class which kind of `List` is really is.  In this case, you don't need the type parameter `T`, only `P`.  You can change your class to this:

```
public class MyClass<P> {
   List<P> getList(/**/){}
   P getRandomElement(){ /**/ }
}
```

Then you can have a `MyClass<String>` whose `getList` method returns an `List<String>` and a `getRandomElement` method that returns a `String`.

Comment: I hoped a less redundant solution had to exists, but if noone comes up with a better approach, I'll accept it thanks!  The list example was just a placeholder, I admit it wouldn't have much sense normally

Comment: How come this solution is redundant?

Comment: @ user2418306 The first one, as I have to pass String twice.